# SQL statement: SELECT data based on a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I want to base my select query on a condition so it is something like:

```
--THE LOGIC TO BE IMPLEMENTED
IF ( SELECT OrderPlacementDate from SellOrders WHERE SellOrders.ProductName = Products.ProductName UNION SELECT OrderPlacementDate from BuyOrders WHERE BuyOrders.ProductName = Products.ProductName is today then :

SELECT Products.ProductName, tblCommun.firstdate
FROM Products
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 OrderPlacementDate as firstdate
             FROM ( SELECT OrderPlacementDate from SellOrders WHERE SellOrders.ProductName = Products.ProductName UNION SELECT OrderPlacementDate from BuyOrders WHERE BuyOrders.ProductName = Products.ProductName) t 
             ORDER BY OrderPlacementDate ASC) tblCommun;
```

The following query gives an output table for the list of all products (where some of these product have no orders for today + products have orders for today) and the date timestamp when a first order was placed for every product:

```
SELECT Products.ProductName, tblCommun.firstdate
FROM Products
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 OrderPlacementDate as firstdate
             FROM ( SELECT OrderPlacementDate from SellOrders WHERE SellOrders.ProductName = Products.ProductName UNION SELECT OrderPlacementDate from BuyOrders WHERE BuyOrders.ProductName = Products.ProductName) t 
             ORDER BY OrderPlacementDate ASC) tblCommun;
```

```
ProductName   | firstdate
---------------------------------------
Apple         | 2021-10-12 13:55:50.100
Orange        | 2021-10-15 08:40:14.670
Carrot        | 2021-10-29 08:45:20.110
```

Example from tables `SellOrders` and `BuyOrders` :

`SellOrders`

```
OrderID  | ProductName  | OrderPlacementDate
-------------------------------------------------
546      | Apple        | 2022-04-20 13:55:30.100
547      | Apple        | 2022-04-20 14:55:50.100
548      | Orange       | 2022-04-20 15:40:50.100
340      | Carrot       | 2022-04-19 13:55:50.100
230      | Carrot       | 2022-04-18 16:50:50.100
```

`BuyOrders`

```
OrderID  | ProductName  | OrderPlacementDate
-------------------------------------------------
500      | Apple        | 2022-04-20 10:55:30.100
540      | Apple        | 2022-04-20 12:55:50.100
267      | Carrot       | 2022-04-19 10:55:50.100
235      | Carrot       | 2022-04-18 15:50:50.100
229      | Orange       | 2022-04-18 13:40:50.100
```

The goal: I want to display only the list of products where there was orders placed today.

Today is `2022-04-20`, so the output table that I wish to have is:

```
ProductName   | firstdate
---------------------------------------
Apple         | 2021-10-12 13:55:50.100
Orange        | 2021-10-15 08:40:14.670
```

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: today in sql server is `select getdate()` and if you only want the date `convert(date, getdate())`

Comment: Thank you for your comment @GuidoG. The problem of implementation that I'm facing is how to apply the condition and not how to get today's date. I need an initial filter on data to be selected in second range.

Comment: in your expected outcome, where does the date 08:40:14 for Orange comes from ?

Comment: You can remark that it is the same date as in the first output table. column `firstdate` stands for the timestamp when a first order was placed for every product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you could use some conditional aggregation in the `HAVING` to check there was an order today:

```sql
WITH Orders AS(
    SELECT SO.ProductID,
           SO.OrderPlacementDate
    FROM dbo.SellOrders SO
    UNION ALL
    SELECT BO.ProductID,
           BO.OrderPlacementDate
    FROM dbo.BuyOrders BO)
SELECT P.ProductName,
       MIN(O.OrderPlacementDate) AS FirstDate
FROM dbo.Product P
     JOIN Orders O ON P.ProductID = O.ProductID
GROUP BY P.ProductName
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN O.OrderPlacementDate >= CONVERT(date,GETDATE()) AND O.OrderPlacementDate < DATEADD(DAY,1,CONVERT(date,GETDATE())) THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

Or, alternatively, you could use an `EXISTS`. I'll leave you to test what is more performant on your environment.

```sql
WITH Orders AS(
    SELECT SO.ProductID,
           SO.OrderPlacementDate
    FROM dbo.SellOrders SO
    UNION ALL
    SELECT BO.ProductID,
           BO.OrderPlacementDate
    FROM dbo.BuyOrders BO)
SELECT P.ProductName,
       MIN(O.OrderPlacementDate) AS FirstDate
FROM dbo.Product P
     JOIN Orders O ON P.ProductID = O.ProductID
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Orders e
              WHERE e.ProductID = O.ProductID
                AND e.OrderPlacementDate >= CONVERT(date,GETDATE())
                AND e.OrderPlacementDate < DATEADD(DAY,1,CONVERT(date,GETDATE())))
GROUP BY P.ProductName;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a5200479781b3be91e938cd4f6d8a4f6)

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE (
SELECT * FROM SellOrders WHERE CONVERT(date, OrderPlacementDate) = 
CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
UNION
SELECT * FROM BuyOrders WHERE CONVERT(date, OrderPlacementDate) = 
CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
) todaysOrders

SELECT DISTINCT p.ProductNmae, p.firstdate FROM Products p 
INNER JOIN todaysOrders t ON t.ProductName = p.ProductName
```

Comment: To get rid of timestamp and ensure that we deal with date only

Comment: Instead of Convert (which will have a bad performance on larger datasets) - it would be better to FILTER by current date. `WHERE OrderPlacementDate BETWEEN CAST(SYSDATETIME() AS DATE) AND CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1, SYSDATETIME()) AS DATE)`

Performing operations on a column is not efficient.

Comment: @GuidoG, simplification...

Comment: @GuidoG, dully noted

Comment: `UNION`, instead of `UNION ALL` seems overkill here, especially with an (incorrectly spelt) `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is using outer apply to get the sells/buys for today

```
select p.ProductName,
       p.FirstDate
from   Products p
  outer apply (select top 1 s.OrderPlacementDate 
               from SellOrders s 
               where s.ProductName = p.ProductName
               and   convert(date, s.OrderPlacementDate) = convert(date, getdate())
              ) sell
  outer apply (select top 1 b.OrderPlacementDate 
               from BuyOrders b
               where b.ProductName = p.ProductName
               and   convert(date, b.OrderPlacementDate) = convert(date, getdate())
              ) buy
where sell.OrderPlacementDate is not null
or buy.OrderPlacementDate is not null
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=602983b15147600d82a2c521dd988918)